# Use the value of an ID to start a countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, countdown

I have a circular progress bar where the user can select the time for a countdown, when the time is chosen the value is saved in an ID but I cannot get this countdown to start from that ID

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.dial').knob({
        'min':0,
        'max':20,
        'width':250,
        'height':250,
        'displayInput':true,
        'fgColor':"#e74c3c",
        'pColor' :"FFA491",


        'release':function(v) {
            document.getElementById('v').innerHTML = v;
        },
   });
    });
  </script>
```

The value is recorded at release and then converted to the ID "v"

I have uploaded the result on this page:https://juanmannnuel.neocities.org/

Comment: Hi Juan! Could you provide more context, ideally an isolated example in codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry the only way to upload it i have found is in neocities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case if you want it to countdown it would looks something like.

```
  $('.dial').knob({
    'min':0,
    'max':20,
    'width':250,
    'height':250,
    'displayInput':true,
    'fgColor':"#e74c3c",
    'pColor' :"FFA491",


    'release':function(v) {
        document.getElementById('v').innerHTML = v;
        $('.dial').val(v).trigger("blur");
    },
   });
```

Could you give a try?

Here is an updated fiddle with countdown.
https://codepen.io/mitkodeli/pen/KKdjQyN

Comment: Sorry, I think I have not expressed myself well, what I want is for the user to decide the seconds in the circular progress bar. After a countdown begins but with numbers not with the bar.

Comment: Could you check if this is the result you are looking for?
https://codepen.io/mitkodeli/pen/KKdjQyN

Comment: After tweaking it a bit in my code I have achieved something decent. It is not what I was looking for initially but it still works for me, thank you very much ;)